# Unified Write Filter API

Tags: api, windows-10

Does someone know, where I can get a description of the UWF API?
I need to check in my code, if UWF is enable, on which device, ...
It seems, all functions are in UWFCFGMGMT.DLL and UWFSERVICINGAPI.DLL.
I couldn't find any documentation about it, even in the MSDN !!
Thx

Fred

Answer (score 4):

There is documentation about the UWF WMI API here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwf-wmi-provider-reference

You can use the WMI interface to use the described WMI functions, e.g.:

```
private bool IsUwfEnabled()
{
    try
    {
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"root\standardcimv2\embedded");
        ManagementClass uwfClass = new ManagementClass(scope.Path.Path, "UWF_Filter", null);

        foreach (var uwfObject in uwfClass.GetInstances())
        {
            return uwfObject["CurrentEnabled"].ToString().Equals("False") ? false : true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Could not determine whether UWF is on!
        // Error handling here
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html

Just download the dll_export.exe from the above mentioned website and read your .dll file functions.
Tested and works perfectly.